# Angular not responding to any routes with ui-router - URL just disappears when I enter

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm using NodeJS+Express to serve an HTML page with an Angular app. It seems to work fine when it loads. There are no errors.

Problem is that that page is pretty much blank - except for the header. But the part that is supposed to go where `<div ui-view></div>` is, doesn't display anything.

Worse yet, when I go to an address, like

```
http://localhost:7070/admin/#/rounds
```

the browser just changes it to

```
http://localhost:7070/admin/#/
```

and goes back to displaying nothing.

My angular app, in `index.js` looks like this:

Some `.run()` and `.config()` settings

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
        // It's  very handy to add references to $state and $stateParams to the $rootScope
        // so that you can access them from any scope within your applications.For example,
        // <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('contacts.list') }"> will set the <li>
        // to active whenever 'contacts.list' or one of its decendents is active.
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }
    ]);

app.config(["$locationProvider", function($locationProvider) {
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

States definition:

```
app.config(
    ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider) {
        console.log("Is this running at all?");
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
        .state("admin", {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/admin',
            template: '<ui-view />'
        })
        .state("admin.login", {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'userLoginCtrl'
        })
        /* DASHBOARD */
        .state("admin.dashboard", {
            url: "",
            controller: 'dashboardAppCtrl',
            templateUrl: "dashboard.html"
        })
        .state("admin.subjects", {
            url: "/subjects",
            controller: 'subjectsCtrl',
            templateUrl: "subjects.html"
        })
        /* ROUNDS */
        .state("admin.rounds", {
            url: "/rounds",
            controller: 'roundsAppCtrl',
            templateUrl: "rounds.html",
            resolve: {
                gameId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    console.log("gameId ");
                    return $stateParams.gameId;
                }]
            }
        })
        .state("admin.round", {
            url: "/round/:roundId",
            controller: 'adminRoundCtrl',
            templateUrl: "adminround.html",
            resolve:{
                gameId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    return $stateParams.gameId;
                }],
                roundId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    return $stateParams.roundId;
                }]
            },
        });
    }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D4sgVqxwoL1bVMHq4cAE?p=preview)

The answer is relatively simple

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/admin');
```

And instead of this

```
http://localhost:7070/admin/#/rounds
```

we have to try this

```
http://localhost:7070/admin/#/admin/rounds
```

The point is, every sub-state `'admin.xxx'` is child state of the the **`'admin'`** state. And that means, it inherits its **`url: '/admin'`**

Also, we used

```
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

So, the startingurl would most likely be ...

*EXTEND: as discussed in comments, IIS Express is used with virtual applicaton **`/admin`**, so this part will be in url twice `/admin/#/admin...`*

```
http://localhost:7070/admin/index.html
// i.e. 
http://localhost:7070/admin/
```

As a starting url of our app. Any routing is later managed after the **`#`** sign

```
http://localhost:7070/admin/#/admin/round/22
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/D4sgVqxwoL1bVMHq4cAE?p=preview)

Comment: It says it cannot GET `http://localhost:7070/#/admin/rounds` and this makes sense because my Express app serves the app for `/admin` path

Comment: Well ok.. that's the /admin part representing the virtual applicaton. not a problem. Just use it twice

Comment: Great if that works, great ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)